# Ng2-charts Time xAxes : unwanted high zoom on click

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts, chartjs-plugin-zoom

I have recently updated to Angular 8 and updated my chart related packages aswell.
I had to update my code to ng2-charts' new data format.
I'm using chartjs-plugin-zoom with my project.

My issue is : 
A very high zoom happens on a single click on my chart, which also happens on a click on the legend.
Another click zooms back out.

I have reproduced the issue in this stackblitz : 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-line-template-czofzn

Is there something I am not doing right? 
Or should I not use time data in coordinates format ?

Answer (score 0):

Time data should be find

```
   zoom: {
        enabled: true,
        drag: false,
        mode: 'x'
      }
```

If you change the drag to false this doesn't happen, but you can still zoom with the mouse wheel